# Get data usage over some given period of time

Tags: android, android-trafficstats

I need to get the amount of data i.e. internet usage over periods of one month.
I have been doing some research and found the `TrafficStats` class. However, it seems confusing. What is the difference between `getUidRxBytes()` and `getUidRxPackets()`.
How can I get the data used over a period of one month?

Answer (score 0):

Use the library [android.net.TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int)) to get the necessary information. You'll have to build an algorithm to calculate that the use of average.

Example:

```
long appDataUsage = android.net.TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(UID);
long total =  android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
```

Comment: But I am only concerned with mobile networks ie- 3G, 4G, And as far as I understand, those methods include WIFI networks

Comment: You're right, the data is mixed.

However, you can monitor the change to Wifi or 3G.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation and found that getMobileRxBytes() returns the data received over 3G,4G,,GPRS. However, the counter gets reset after the phone shuts down. Would you recommend setting up a db to store this data?

Comment: I recommend saving the data in the database, but can be used SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you!
One last question, and I apologize for my ignorance, but how do companies like Verizon measure the data usage? Do they add up the receive and sent(transmit) value or either of them?

Comment: I do not quite understand how it's done by companies, but they have a lot of information about your sim-card GSM that is logged in their network. With their identification they can make the amount of data you are sending and receiving for their network.

Comment: I'll keep you posted on how it goes!